# Cant find V2Listener when calling Service Fabric Actor Service by URI

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, actor, service-fabric-actor

Trying to get a list of all actors in a actor service i get an AggregateException.

> System.AggregateException: FabricInvalidAddressException: NamedEndpoint 'V2Listener' not found in the address '{"Endpoints":{"V2_1Listener":"LautarosMonster:30006+f87ebfe0-9f5c-435f-ac5a-a62ab13eda5d-132059632019035414-bf7ac379-8bc1-4c52-a5b2-339efc840b5b"}}' for partition 'f87ebfe0-9f5c-435f-ac5a-a62ab13eda5d'

Here i get the UserActors:

```
       async public Task<List<string>> GetUserActors()
    {
        ContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource().Token;
        List<ActorInformation> activeActors = new List<ActorInformation>();

        do
        {
            var proxy = GetUserActorServiceProxy();
            PagedResult<ActorInformation> page = await proxy.GetActorsAsync(continuationToken, cancellationToken);

            activeActors.AddRange(page.Items.Where(x => x.IsActive));

            continuationToken = page.ContinuationToken;
        }
        while (continuationToken != null);

        return activeActors.Select(aa => aa.ActorId.ToString()).ToList();
    }
```

Im pretty sure i got the URI naming convention right. This is how i get the actorServiceProxy

> ```
>   public IActorService GetUserActorServiceProxy()
>     {   
>         var proxy = ActorServiceProxy.Create(new Uri("fabric:/ECommerce/UserActorService"), 0);
>         return proxy;
>     }
> ```

The application name is "ECommerce" and the service im trying to call is "UserActor"

The exception is thrown on the PagedResult line where i call proxy.GetActorsAsync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is the same **bug** i raised here?

https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric-services-and-actors-dotnet/issues/159

Comment: Yes! I just saw it last night. I tried the suggested solution and used "IActorService serviceProxy = ServiceProxy.Create<IActorService>(new Uri(serviceUris[i]), new ServicePartitionKey(partitionKey));" instead. 

I no longer get the error but on the other hand it returns no actors either. Its always zero. Even if i just add some actors everytime i run this code, just to have some test actors.